# Unit Testing show action of a controller with findwhere in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am trying to unit test show action of a controller. It's definition is :

```
def show = {
        //scs 11/22/2011 limit access to users in their Organization
        def currentOrgViewCheck = session.currentUserOrganizationId.viewAllPost;
        def currentOrg = session.currentUserOrganizationId;

        def addressesInstance ;
        if(currentOrgViewCheck){
            addressesInstance = Addresses.findWhere(id:Long.parseLong(params.id));
        }else{
            addressesInstance = Addresses.findWhere(id:Long.parseLong(params.id), organization:currentOrg);
        }


        if (!addressesInstance) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'addresses.label', default: 'Addresses'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {
            [addressesInstance: addressesInstance]
        }
    }
```

I am trying to test it by mocking the Addresses domain, then creating and saving one instance of Addresses and finally passing it's id to params of controller. But the test is not passing.
Also I tried to test the findWhere method on my unit test method, whatever arguments I give it, it keep on saying that missingMethodException, that no such signature exists for the given data type. I am totally stuck. Here is my testing code :

```
void testShowFound()
   {
       // New Controller to test
       ac = new AddressesController();

       // this instance is required both to test as well as a session variable
       Organizations org = new Organizations(name:'test', phone: '352-999-8888', createdBy: creator, modifiedBy: modifier, viewAllPost: true);
       org.save();

       //Create an address to pass its id to the action as parameter.
       Addresses a1 = new thlc.Addresses(firstLine:'A1', secondLine:'B', thirdLine:'C', luCountry:UnitedStates, zipCode:'12345', luState:Florida, city:'jag');
       a1.save();   

       ac.metaClass.getParams = {->[id:a1.id] }
       //ac.params.id = a1.id; // I tried both ways.



        // This findWhere is giving error, can any one explain why ?
       //def a = Addresses.findWhere(id:a1.id);
       //assertEquals(a, a1);

       //session variables mocked.
       mockSession['currentUserOrganizationId'] = org;

       // This is to bypass the flash message problem, cause it is not possible to
       // mock the message method on flash messages.
       //ac.metaClass.message = { Map map -> return "ByPass Message" }

       //Call the action and test
       def model = ac.save();
       assert(model);

       //Testing redirect, This is the test that is failing
       assertEquals("list", redirectParams.action);
   }
```

I have tried most of the things, but just cant work around it. what am I missing ? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but `Addresses.findWhere(id:Long.parseLong(params.id));` is way too verbose; just use `Addresses.get(params.id)` since it's equivalent and will convert the param to the correct type

Comment: Oh god yes, that is correct. But It is the code that I am only supposed to test and not change. Sad.

Comment: where is your test failing?  Is it at a1.save() in your test or Address.findWhere(..) in the controller?

Comment: Can you post the method where you do `mockDomain()`? You didn't mention you mock domain for `Organizations`.

Comment: I am doing mockDomain() in setup for both Organizations and Addresses.

Comment: My Test is failing in assertEquals Line.

Comment: Is it failing at assert(model); or at Addresses.findWhere(...)?  Because failing at the assertEquals is not the same issue as missingMethodException.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in Grails 1.3.7 (and below) `mockDomain` does not create the findWhere() dynamic finder. From the sounds of it you have to mock the method yourself if you want to use it. I haven't done this myself yet.

References:

http://www.slideshare.net/tlberglund/test-first-refresh-second-testdriven-development-in-grails (Slide 38)

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/New-approach-to-mocking-domain-classes-in-Grails-unit-tests-td2529895.html

Comment: "Anonymous" provided this in a rejected edit of your answer: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4356 Mocked domain class does not provide findWhere results - Fixed in 1.4-M1